# Analysing a sentence taken from a lesson

Tags: parts-of-speech

Children and adults alike are fond of folktales. 
What is the part of speech of 'alike' ? What does it modify?

Answer (score 1):

> [*Children*] [*and adults alike*] *are fond of folktales*.

"Alike" is an adverb here in a set comparison construction, where it functions as an adjunct (modifier) in the structure of the second coordinate, as bracketed.

The modifier serves to reinforce the relation expressed by the coordinator.

Answer (score -3):

> Children and adults alike are fond of folktales.

**Alike** is an adverb in this sentence. It modifies the adjective *fond*.

As an adverb *[alike](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/alike)* means 'in the same way',  'in a similar way' or '[equally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alike)'.

> Children and adults are equally fond of folktales.

Comment: @Nancy No, it's not the right answer. "Alike" does not modify "fond". Its a modifier in the second coordinate "and adults alike", i.e. "[Children] [and adults alike] are fond of folktales".

Comment: Sorry, but I had to downvote your answer. Please see my comment above to Nancy.

Comment: @BillJ then how it becomes an adverb?

Comment: @BillJ Surely the answer is simply that 'alike' is an adverb modifying 'are'. This is because there is no verb 'to fond' since 'fond' is always an adjective.

Comment: But the words that modify 'is' , 'are' are always adjectives. An adverb can't modify 'are' at all.

Comment: @BoldBen How can an adverb be seen to be modifying copular "are"? Comparative constructions like this can have modifiers like "alike", "too" or "as well" in the second coordinate, cf. "[The children] [and the adults too/ as well] are fond of folktales".

Comment: @BoldBen An adverb can modify a verb, an adjective and another adverb. *Fond* is an adjective, and it can be modified by an adverb. As: *less fond of; more fond of; too fond of; **alike fond of***

Comment: @mahmudkoya That's not how it works here. You can't say "alike fond of" -- that's impossible. As I just explained adverbs like "alike", too, (and the PP "as well") modify the second coordinate. You need to learn about coordinate constructions.